# GDB step over command

Tags: c, operating-system, gdb, bootloader, att

I have the following C code:

```
#include <inc/x86.h>
#include <inc/elf.h>

#define SECTSIZE 512
#define ELFHDR  ((struct Elf *)0x10000) // Scratch space

void readsect(void*, unit32_t);
void readsec(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t);

void bootmain(void)
{
    struct Proghdr *ph, *eph;

    // Read the first page off disk
    readseg((uint32_t) ELFHDR, SECTSIZE*8, 0);
    .
    .  // The rest of the code
    .
}
```

I am using GDB to step in my code and see what is happening.

I found the address of bootmain `0x7d0a` and I put a breakpoint there.

```
b *0x7d0a
c
```

The above two commands: `b` adds a breakpoint and `c` runs until the breakpoint is reached.

I can see that I stopped at `0x7d0a` as expected.

Then after a few commands I can see the function parameters being pushed to the stack as arguments. And a call for `readseg`.

```
0x7d0f push $0x0      // 0
0x7d11 push $0x1000   // 512*8 = 4096 B
0x7d16 push $0x10000  // 64 KB
0x7d1b call 0x7cd1
```

How do I just step over this function? The next command using `si` just gets me inside the `readseg` function. I don't want to step into, but to step over. I tried putting a breakpoint next to the next command:

```
    b *0x7d21
    c
```

But it never returns...

Should I perhaps have set the breakpoint on a different address?

I am not sure. However this is a way around and I'd rather use the step over command which I couldn't find in the documentation [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html).

Comment: Why are you using hex addresses instead of statement line numbers when you set your breakpoints?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't understand what you mean ? because I need the address of a specific instruction in my code.

Comment: @TonyTannous You can say `break bootmain` to GDB, it's easier than `break *0x7d0a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "step over" analogue of `si` is called `nexti` (also abbreviated `ni`).  This will step a single assembly instruction, but step over calls.

Comment: Didn't work. `nexti` after `call 0x7cd1` didn't show `0x7d61` which is next command. But showed the next command address as: `0x7cd1` that means it went in. :/

Comment: How about plain `n`? That's what I use for 'next line'. And `s` for 'step into'.

Comment: If `ni` isn't working and `break` on the following instruction isn't triggering, then maybe the problem is that the call isn't returning.